# wifi signal enhancement from a distance?

Tags: wireless-networking

I get wifi from across the street, and the signal is very weak, except maybe for the closest point of the house. What kind of tools are available to me to enhance the signal, so that I can enhance the signal ? Is there any kind of signal repetition item that I could buy ?

Comment: A wifi range extender should do the job... E.g. http://theawesomer.com/photos/2011/06/061311_netgear_wifi_range_extender_4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Wifi directional antenna is probably what you are looking for. Google it up there are many DIY projects in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

and if that can't help you, create a disk like a parabola disk using aluminum foil as the disk that center on the antenna...